# Auto Command fails with file plugin command

Tags: neovim, autocmd

I have following line in my `.nvimrc`

> au! BufWritePost *.elm ElmMake

Each time I save an elm file vim tells me that this command does not exist.
However I am able to run this command in command more while editing elm file, so there is no doubt in my mind that this command does exist.

I should point out that `ElmMake` command came with filetype plugin so apparently commands in vimrc are ran in different filetype(`vim`?)

Which leads me to my question how can  I access file type specific commands inside my vimrc?

Comment: autocommand you showed us should work

Comment: Ah! Didn't notice exclamation mark, try remove it `au BufWritePost *.elm ElmMake`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem you're having is due to the command being registered with `-buffer`, which means it's only available in buffers of filetype "elm" and for some reason are not available in the autocmd.

Why that is happening, I can't really tell... The event you're using (`BufWritePost`) is a buffer-specific example and I'd also expect it to run while the buffer is still around... But I might be wrong about that part perhaps...

It's not the case that this will be evaluated in a filetype `vim` context, the autocmd commands are only really evaluated when called, not when they're defined. So not really sure what's going on there...

I can try to suggest a workaround though.

The [definition of the `ElmMake` command](https://github.com/ElmCast/elm-vim/blob/165107a9fd2b20c8f050fc4f977b4e41c790b1e7/ftplugin/elm.vim#L44) reads:

```
command -buffer -nargs=? -complete=file ElmMake call elm#Make(<f-args>)
```

So calling it without any arguments should be the equivalent to:

```
call elm#Make()
```

So just call that directly from your autocmd instead. The function definition is global and should work from any context.

For best practice, put it in an `augroup` block, so it gets properly updated when you reload your vimrc:

```
augroup vimrc_elm
  au!
  au BufWritePost *.elm call elm#Make()
augroup END
```

Hopefully that will solve the problem!

Comment: Thank yo that's very helpful. Seems to have solved it/exposed the error in Make function itself XD

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you try to add an autocommand but remove it instead:

```
3. Removing autocommands                *autocmd-remove*

:au[tocmd]! [group] {event} {pat} [++once] [++nested] {cmd}
            Remove all autocommands associated with {event} and
            {pat}, and add the command {cmd}.
...
```

Try it without exclamation mark.

Also, generally it is a good idea to put autocommands to autogroups, like:

```
augroup ELM_MAKE | autocmd!
    au BufWritePost *.elm ElmMake
augroup end
```

It creates autocommand group and cleans it up with `autocmd!` before any autocommand definition. Otherwise each reload of your vimrc (`:so $MYVIMRC` for example) would create duplicate autocommands.

Comment: You missed the part that says `and add the command {cmd}`. So that `au!` line is somewhat legit, in that it will set that autocmd correctly (replacing any others for the same event/pattern.) So while I agree with your suggestion, it's not really an answer to this question.

Comment: @filbranden indeed, I had interpreted documentation in a wrong way.